# MediaRecorder.prepare() exception - No such file or directory

Tags: android, exception, audio, record

I'm trying to record audio, a wild exception appears when the debug arrives to `.prepare()`

This is my `Record()` method.

```
private void Grabar(View v) {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 
    String nombrefichero =  String.valueOf(today.getDate()) + "-"
            + String.valueOf(today.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
            + String.valueOf(today.getYear() + 1900) + "_"
            + String.valueOf(today.getHours()) + "."
            + String.valueOf(today.getMinutes())+"."+String.valueOf(today.getSeconds()) +".3gp";

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(VarGlobales.Ruta+"/"+VarGlobales.Trabajo+"/Audio/"+nombrefichero);
    // VarGlobales.Ruta -> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    // VarGlobales.Trabajo -> 001
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
        Toast.makeText(contexto, "Grabando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(contexto, "Fallo en la grabación", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }       
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml has `RECORD_AUDIO` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

Exception says:

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/001/Audio/25-7-2014_8.53.6.3gp:
> open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> ```

The exception says that the file does not exist. Do not suppose I'm creating it right now?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try moving your call to `setOutputFormat()` to before the call to `setOutputFile()`.

Comment: Are you testing on a device or an emulator?

Comment: @MikeM.If i do that i get a java.lang.IllegalStateException.

Comment: Try this specific order: `setAudioSource()` => `setOutputFormat()` => `setAudioEncoder()` => `setOutputFile()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read the documentation. It says that **`mediaRecorder.setOutputFile()`** should be called after **`setOutputFormat()`** and before **`prepare()`**.

//To create a directory in sdcard:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/";
File dir = new File(path);
if(!dir.exists())
dir.mkdirs();
String myfile = path + "filename" + ".mp4";
```

Then specify this as your output file.

```
setOutputFile(myfile);
```

Comment: The log output says that no such file or directory. So, i think you didnt create the directory or the file. I'll edit my code, pls try it.